# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как работает код

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как работает код.

```
a, b, c = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
if (a < 0):    
    a = 0    
if (b < 0):    
    b = 0
if (c < 0):
    c = 0
print(a + b + c)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код чужой, я просто пытаюсь понять как он работает.

print при суммировании переменных, выдает ответ 5 (как показано на картинке), разве при складывании "a+b+c" print не должен вывести "0". Ведь значения переменных после каждого оператора if было перебито и стало = 0?

Объясните пожалуйста, почему ответ  "5", а не  "0"

Comment: `if (b < 0): b = 0` — очевидно, -22 меньше чем 0, поэтому b становится нулём, и в итоге 4 + 0 + 1 = 5

Comment: «Ведь значения переменных» — переменнОЙ. Одной переменной b = 0. Переменные a и c никто не трогал, потому что они больше нуля и блоки под их операторами if не выполнились

Comment: Ты точно знаешь, что делает if?

Answer (score 1):

Вы ввели два положительных числа и одно отрицательное.

Условия **if** для каждой переменной в данном коде проверяют, является переменная меньше нуля или нет. Если да, то делает равной 0, а если больше нуля, то оставляет число, как есть.

Поэтому переменная **b** попала под условие b < 0 (меньше нуля) и стала 0).

Переменные **a** и **c** остались без изменении так, как они больше 0.

Соответственно 4 + 0 + 1 = 5

Comment: *Переменные a и b остались без изменении* - может быть, a и **с**?

Comment: Благодарю, опечатался.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. А каким образом здесь работает print? Мы задали значения новым переменным, после каждого If, тем самым переписав, переменные со значением int(input) и присвоив им новые значения. То есть 4 не меньше 0, то программа выдаст "ничего" или "пустое место", тогда как print при считывании кода сможет увидеть это пустое место, почему программа не ругается, что здесь неверное значение. Из вашего комментария я поняла, что 4 и 1 остается без изменений, но каким образом?

Comment: Вам необходимо разобраться, как работают условные операторы if/else. Если условие if не выполняется, то этот код просто пропускается. Откуда пустое место там должно появиться? 4 не меньше нуля, значит блок с присваиванием 0 не выполняется и переменную вообще никак не трогают. Её не стирают, не переписывают, а просто оставляют, как есть. Я не совсем понимаю суть Вашего вопроса. Если бы вы задали код if a < 0: a = 0 else: a = <ваше значение или "пустота">, тогда ещё куда ни шло.